# SSH timed out when trying to connect to Raspi from outside of my local network

Tags: raspberry-pi, sshd, port-forwarding

I'm trying to connect to my raspberry pi outside my local network with ssh.

I can connect inside my local network.

My pi has a fixed ip address and port forwarding is set properly.

My ssh port has been changed from 22 to another one, which was free.

The command I am using:

```
ssh -vvvp 49100 pi@**.***.**.*
```

Here is the verbose output of ssh command:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to **.***.**.* port 49100.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to **.***.**.*:49100 as 'pi'
debug3: put_host_port: [**.***.**.*]:49100
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/armandfardeau/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: looks like connection is dropped, check forwarding rule 49100@external.ip => 22@pi.address (or 49100@pi.adress)

Comment: Does running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` in the raspbian side solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like well known MTU/fragmentation problem. Replace MTU for both ssh-server and ssh-client network interfaces with a same smaller value. Let's assume your network interface ssh listens is `eth0` (detect it using `ifconfig`). Check current MTU value for the interface:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/mtu
```

Replace temporarily your current MTU (which is 1500 probably) for the interface with a lesser number, for example:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1496
```

or

```
echo 1496 | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/mtu
```

If the number 1496 hasn't solved problem, try MTU 1250 etc. If the problem goes away with some MTU value, make the changes for interface persistent.

Read this carefully: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html